# Unable to locate element message

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to enter data in the ID field but seeing the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"attribute.ID"}
```

Tried various elements but it doesn't it is able to find the input field on the screen.

Using Inspect Element (Q) in FireFox under Inspector scrolling title

```
iframe#iframe01 > html..js... > body... > div#cpo-folder > div.cpo-content-wrapper > div.cpo-content > iframe#iframe02 > html > frameset > frame > html... > body#SearchFilter > div.dt-filter.filter > form#filterForm > table.tbody > tr > input
```

HTML code

```
<html class="..." lang="en">
   <iframe name="iframe01" id="iframe01" src="..." title="Navigation" scrolling="no" lang="en">
      <html class="..." lang="en">
         <iframe id="iframe02" name="iframe02" class="..." title="Main" frameborder="0" lang="en">
            <html lang="en">
                <frameset rows="150px,*" border="0">
                    <frame name="frame01" src="..." title="Results" noresize="">
                        <html ...>
                            <body id="SearchFilter" onunload="destroy()">
                                <h1> Identifier Search </h1>
                                <div class="dt-filter filter" style="display: block">
                                    <form id="filterForm" action="..." method="POST" target="Results">
                                        <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="label" nowrap="">ID</td>
                                                    <td><input name="attribute.ID" size="20" tabindex="1" type="text"></td>
                                                    <td class="label" nowrap=""></td>
                                                    <td><tabindex=4></tabindex=4></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                    </frame>
                </frameset>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Java Code:

```
public static void click_IdentifierSearch() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframe01");
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframe02");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("attribute.ID")).sendKeys("123456789"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `input` element is inside three frames while your are switching only two frames you need to switch third frame as well and `input` element has name attribute value `attribute.ID` instead of id, so you should try as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe01");
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe02");
driver.switchTo().frame("frame01");
driver.findElement(By.name("attribute.ID")).sendKeys("123456789");
```

**Note** :- `driver.switchTo().frame();` uses to switching for `frame` and `iframe` both.